# What does an app save in order to stay logged in to a Microsoft app with a public account?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, credentials, refresh-token

I have an OK understanding of refresh tokens and access tokens. But if an AT has a 1 hr expiry and a RT has 24 hrs, how do I stay logged in to a Microsoft app for weeks or months without having to login again?

Is it as simple as saving my credentials and the app simply uses them to get an AT and RT after 24 hrs? Or is there another caching artefact I'm not aware of?

I want an app I am developing to provide my server with a client AT so it can access msgraph on behalf of the user (it's got consent).

But I don't want the user having to login every day. I looked in to app-only but am having issues with public accounts, so a behalf of permission is my work around... I just don't want the user logging in every day.

BONUS query... how do I get about MFA?

I've read a lot on the MS learn on AT and RT and ID tokens. Also the msal libraries, but unclear regarding what's caching or how to get around the refresh 24 hr expiry.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an OK understanding of refresh tokens and access tokens. But if an AT has a 1 hr expiry and a RT has 24 hrs, how do I stay logged in to a Microsoft app for weeks or months without having to login again?

The app will need new tokens once the refresh token has expired.
In a single page web application for example, it will need to redirect/popup the login page to do this.
Since your session with Azure AD is still valid at this point, the app receives new tokens without asking the user anything.

> Is it as simple as saving my credentials and the app simply uses them to get an AT and RT after 24 hrs? Or is there another caching artefact I'm not aware of?

An app should never save your username and password.
This would be actively working against the security provided by the authentication flows.

> I want an app I am developing to provide my server with a client AT so it can access msgraph on behalf of the user (it's got consent).

> But I don't want the user having to login every day. I looked in to app-only but am having issues with public accounts, so a behalf of permission is my work around... I just don't want the user logging in every day.

So if you are doing this MS Graph API access while the user is actively using your app, you can simply acquire an access token using MSAL.
Even if your refresh token has expired, there is a good chance it'll be able to acquire new tokens without requiring the user to log in again since their session is still active.

If you want to access the API in the background while the user is not actively using your app, then you will need a back-end and start the authentication from there.
You will then get refresh tokens that are valid for several days, and can be refreshed without user interaction.
This is a topic of its own though, so I'd like to hear what your scenario is first.

> BONUS query... how do I get about MFA?

You don't need to think about MFA at all if you use the standard authentication flows.
Whether the user goes through MFA or not is purely a concern of Azure AD while the user is logging in.

Comment: We have options. 1) User consents to app, granting app-only permissions. Backend authenticates and uses its app creds to access user resources. However, I believe a public account cannot grant app-only consent. So I think this is not an option because of this. 2) User logs in, consents, and provides a token to the backend, so thr backend can get a refresh and access token. The user will periodically use the app and provide a new token, but how do we prevent the need for the user to log in to MS every few days. E.g. my outlook app doesn't ask me to signin, and it's been months.

Comment: 1) Yes, a public client cannot use application permissions since it cannot hold secrets. You would need a back-end. 2) Right, I think Windows apps are slightly different here. Windows stores something known as the "primary refresh token" for your account. All of the apps are able to use that to get new tokens as far as I am aware.

Comment: Ah. So if we have to rely on delegated permissions, is there no method to make it easier for the user and not login every day? Every 3 months isn't as bad, but every 24hrs will suck. It seems I never have to login to MS resources, curious how that works... e.g. browser. And how do phones keep a sync with mailboxes? I get we can use a refresh token for 24 hours, but if the user needs to access a token, they will have to login each time, can we have that login semi automated for the user?

Comment: In some cases when you use a refresh token, you'll get a new refresh token that has a new validity time. I'm not sure in which cases that will occur for public clients though :\